# How to set placeholder property to text field in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

**code:**

```
var text='<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.commons.TextField" id="TF5" data-value="69190"></div>';
                var myView = sap.ui.view({id:"myView",viewContent:text, type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.HTML});
                myView.placeAt("content3");
```

Here how can i give placeholder?

Answer (score 1):

Are you working with JS views?

TextFields have a porperty called placheolder, use the api reference to look up properties for controls: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.TextField.html#constructor

This will work:

```
var text = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
    placeholder: "my text"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using HTML-Views, this solution should work:

```
var text = '<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.commons.TextField" id="TF5" data-value="69190" data-placeholder="My Placeholder"></div>';
var myView = sap.ui.view({
    id: "myView",
    viewContent: text, 
    type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.HTML
});
myView.placeAt("content3");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no default option for that but check this link: 
http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/01/05/adding-placeholder-functionality-for-textfield-in-sapui5

Comment: thanks but i get the another approach is var textfield = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
    placeholder : 'type here'
   
   });

Comment: Thanks, I haven't done enough research I think, really thought it didn't exist.